# add pager active class when slider starts changing items

Tags: javascript, jquery, bxslider

I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NXzcx/148/)

It is very similiar to my task just there is one issue, how you see now first item has active class but when slider autostarts that active class doesn't add to next or previous item, only when you click each of left item in this case it receives active class. So I want to add active class to every current item when slider autorotates.

```
$(function() {

    var slider = $('#banner-slider').bxSlider({
        controls: true,
        mode: 'vertical',
        auto: true,
        pager:true
    });

    $('.banner-pager a').click(function() {
        var thumbIndex = $('..banner-pager a').index(this);
        slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);

        $('.banner-pager a').removeClass('pager-active');
        $(this).addClass('pager-active');
        return false;
    });

    $('.banner-pager a:first').addClass('pager-active');

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can upgrade to a newer version of bxslider, then you can use the callbacks like

```js
$(function() {
  $(function() {
    var $as = $('.banner-pager a');

    // assign the slider to a variable
    var slider = $('#banner-slider').bxSlider({
      controls: true,
      mode: 'vertical',
      auto: true,
      pager: true,
      onSlideAfter: function($el, pidx, idx) {
        $as.eq(pidx).removeClass('pager-active');
        $as.eq(idx).addClass('pager-active');
      }
    });

    $as.click(function() {
      var thumbIndex = $as.index(this);
      slider.goToSlide(thumbIndex);
      return false;
    });

    // assign "pager-active" class to the first thumb
    $('.banner-pager a:first').addClass('pager-active');

  });
});
```

```css
    #banner {
      height: 294px;
      width: 100%;
      position: relative;
      background: #e5e5e5;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    .banner-nav {
      max-width: 260px;
      width: auto;
      height: 294px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      background: #cccccc;
      position: absolute;
    }
    .banner-pager a {
      width: 220px;
      display: block;
      float: left;
      height: 18px;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      color: #111;
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .banner-pager a.pager-active,
    .banner-pager a:hover {
      background: #e5e5e5;
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .banner-wrap {
      float: left;
      height: 294px;
      padding-left: 260px;
    }
    .banner-slide {
      height: 294px;
      width: 720px;
    }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bxslider/4.2.5/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>

<div id="banner">
  <div class="banner-nav">
    <div class="banner-pager">
      <a href="">Dubery Wotsit</a>
      <a href="">Laterz on a'menjey</a>
      <a href="">Joben</a>
      <a href="">Tukka Tukka</a>
      <a href="">Horse Hair Duvet</a>
      <a href="">FML</a>
      <a href="">Balls Deep</a>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <ul id="banner-slider">
      <li style="background: #FF0000;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Dubery Wotsit</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #FF8000;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Laterz on a'menjey</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #FFFF00;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Joben</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #80FF00;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Tukka Tukka</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #00FF00;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Horse Hair Duvet</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #00FF80;">
        <div class="banner-slide">FML</div>
      </li>
      <li style="background: #00FFFF;">
        <div class="banner-slide">Balls Deep</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```